# Pydev for Eclipse does not change all reference when renaming package

Tags: python, eclipse, refactoring, pydev

I would expect the pydev package to rename all references in a project when rafactoring a module name. However, this is not the case. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Please post a bug report in PyDev (http://pydev.org/faq.html#how_do_i_report_a_bug) -- I'll take a look at it :)

Comment: Fabio, was there any progress on this? pydev 2.7.1 seems to still have this problem. References and imports are not updated when package is moved or renamed, or when module is moved or renamed. 
And BTW - thanks for PyDev!

Answer (score 0):

delete the project in eclipse and then create a new project in eclipse with the projects new name. This will automatically add the projects contents into the new project